# Show that $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}[\frac{1}{n},1]=(0,1]$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Show that $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}[\frac{1}{n},1]=(0,1]$.

I struggle a bit with "mathematical reasoning" it would seem, but since everything in life is a matter of experience, I seek advice too check if this is OK!

This tasks are trivial, but proof writing is perhaps not so easy...

My attempt:

Since $\frac{1}{N}>0$ for all $N \in \mathbb{N}$, $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}[\frac{1}{n},1] \subset (0,1]$.

Since $\frac{1}{n}\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$ but $\frac{1}{N}\neq 0$ for all $N \in \mathbb{N}$, $(0,1] \subset \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}[\frac{1}{n},1]$

Thus $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}[\frac{1}{n},1]=(0,1]$.

Comment: Hello @NumberMan. Can you try with double Inclusion. If $A \subset B$, and $B \subset A$, then $A = B $. In some point you will need to use the Archimedian property

Comment: I believed I did double inclusion! But perhaps it's a error.

Comment: let 1>e>0, by archimedian property exists some n such 1/n < e, so e is in [1/n, 1]. Therefore (0,1} is in the big Union of the intervals of form [1/m, 1] for m in N

Comment: Your argument looks fine to me! It seems clear to me that you are using a double-inclusion argument. Also, "$1/n \to 0$" is exactly the Archimedian property. It's possible that you'd be expected to give a tiny bit more detail about the second inclusion though. I don't understand @bbbbbbbbb's comment at all - the statement in the title is correct. The LHS contains many irrational numbers, as a union of intervals.

Comment: Thanks, everyone! I guess it's better to use the Archimedean property which is more "basic" than limit-arguments...

Comment: Yeah, I've mistakenly interpreted the `[1/n, n]` range as a set of 2 values.

Comment: I think, that you should give a definition of an infinite union and base the proof in both directions on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your argument works, but since I assume that this is for an introductory class, I think you should argue a little more precisely, and follow that "standard way" of proving set equality. In the following proof, I will do exactly what you have done, but in a more standard and precise manner.

**Prove that $\cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\left[\frac{1}{n}, 1\right] = (0, 1]$**

*LHS $\subset$ RHS:*

Let $x \in \cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\left[\frac{1}{n}, 1\right]$. Then there exists $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x\in \left[\frac{1}{N}, 1\right]$, and since $\frac{1}{N}>0$, we have that $x \in (0,1]$.

*RHS $\subset$ LHS:*

Let $x \in (0,1]$. Since $x>0$, there exists $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x >\frac{1}{N}$ (archimedean property). Therefore, we have that

$x\in \left(\frac{1}{N}, 1\right]\subset (0,1]$

and we're done $\square$.

To reiterate, your argument is ok, but since you're gonna do lots and lots of set equality proofs in your upcomming future, it is good to try to do the simple ones in the standard way.